# Why won't my butter and milk mix when trying to make cream?

Tags: substitutions

I wanted to make a heavy cream substitute.

Here's what I tried:

1. Melted butter and stored it in a cup.

   - **The pot I melted it in was not washed.**
2. Used the same pot to boil milk.

   - Afterward, **the milk looked yellowish with bubbles on it.**
3. Strained the milk and put it in the refrigerator until it's cool.
4. Added the melted butter to the milk.

   - They wouldn't mix. They stayed separate like oil and water.

My questions:

- Why wouldn't they mix? And how do I get them to mix?
- Why did the milk look that way? Was it because of the remaining butter in the pot?
- How can I make use out of this milk and butter?

Comment: Two questions. 1. Is it curdling or simply not mixing? 2. What are you trying to use the heavy cream for? If you are cooking with it (adding to a sauce or cake recipe) you can probably use this as long as it is only separated and not curdled, but you may need to add something else to get it to blend. If it is curdled you can make fresh cheese like paneer, but the butter may be wasted. (maybe if you chill it, the butter may float to the top and solidify and you could skim it off.)

Comment: No,it's not curdling....just the butter wouldn't mix....yesterday I threw it away and started over again with the same milk and butter...this time I used separate pots for melting butter and boiling milk....but even then they could see the bubbles...so I stirred for so long and kept it in the fridge...today morning I saw it thickened up and curdled only a bit...and the butter totally separated from the milk.....now I'm confused what's my fault this time!!

Comment: And I was trying to use it To prepare hot chocolate!!

Comment: The reason it looks like oil and water is that it, essentially is...  Milk is largely water and butter is mostly fat... you can't make them mix. Regardless, most hot chocolate that I've run into is made with milk, not cream.

Comment: For hot chocolate, as noted already, plain milk is usually eminently acceptable. If you really want to increase the fat content for the hot chocolate, melt some butter or coconut oil (probably very very little -- a small spoon of it only, maybe half a teaspoon) and mix it into the chocolate, then mix the milk in gradually over heat. Don't boil it at this point. If you are boiling it for safety, do that first and mix it off of the heat. In my experience, boiling high fat milk products tends to encourage them to separate and sometimes curdle, depending on whatever else is in there.

Comment: @NadjaCS thanks dude!! I'll give it a try!!After all these disasters  Making heavy cream substitute at home is impossible now!!

Comment: @catija that's what I know too!! But in most tutorials they prepare homemade heavy cream with these two (butter and milk)... 3/4cup of milk and 1/4cup of melted butter is used in this recipe.....and as they said in the tutorials (even showed) that the milk and butter mix together and when refrigerated forms a creamy texture,which is not too thick or fluffy like whipped cream....but a bit liquidy like normal heavy cream..... And yes, using heavy cream in the hot chocolate makes it thicker and rich.....that's why I tried it.... :)

Answer (score 2):

I was thinking that this is a duplicate, but I can't find an original, and somebody edited it to be readable, so I will answer.

1. They didn't mix, because they can't mix. You can't get them to mix. There is no way to make whipping cream out of milk and butter.
2. The milk looked that way because there were bubbles of melted butter swimming in it.
3. Use it in any recipe which requires some milk and some butter without caring about the order. Pancake batter, casserole topping, etc.

Comment: I was not trying to make whipping cream....I wanted to make heavy cream to use it in making hot chocolate .....and I learnt it from YouTube that mixing melted butter and milk would be enough for a substitute....in the tutorial they mixed perfectly!!

Comment: Only if I could show u a picture of it?? Isn't there any option to send pictures??

Comment: @NoorESiddikaSwapnil Heavy cream and whipping cream are basically the same thing. They might be slightly different fat contents, but the exact numbers probably depend on where you live, and it's not worth worrying about. The answer is the same for both: you can't mix that much oil into milk.

Comment: It's not exactly a duplicate. The one your are thinking of I also participated in. That question was really about making double cream (48%). Took me a while to find it, but it's not a dupe. Good news is you aren't crazy :-)

Comment: @Jefromi  that's what I know too!! But in most tutorials they prepare homemade heavy cream out of these two (butter and milk)... 3/4cup of milk and 1/4cup of melted butter is used in this recipe.....and as they said in the tutorials (even showed) that the milk and butter mix together and when refrigerated forms a creamy texture,which is not too thick or fluffy like whipped cream....but a bit liquidy like normal heavy cream..... And yes, using heavy cream in the hot chocolate makes it thicker and rich.....that's why I tried it.... :)